# Error when trying to execute query from the code to SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite

This code throws an error

> Input string was not in a correct format

in Visual Studio; but when I execute it on SQLite directly, it works:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Subjects(ID, Title, Title_alt,NameTranslation)" +
                                   "SELECT DISTINCT SubjectId, Name_alt,Name ,'{''en'':''' || Name || '''}&{''ar'':''' || Name_alt || '''} ' as NameTranslation   FROM Atta_Subject");
```

The problem is within the

```
'{''en'':''' || Name || '''}&{''ar'':''' || Name_alt || '''} ' as NameTranslation
```

But I can't figure out what is it

Comment: What happen if you reduce all three quote blocks to blocks of two quotes?

Comment: Format results in the application code. Database responsibility is saving and reading data. Load required data that map it to expected output in the c# code, which will be simpler, more readable and maintainable.

Comment: But shouldn't it just executes the query as if I executed it on SQL lite directly?